# "wctomb" output => What is encoding in multibyte output of wctomb API?

Tags: unicode

While working on Unicode, I came across "wctomb" API which is used to convert wide character to multibyte equivalent, my query is that UTF-8, UTF 16 both are considered to be mutibyte encoding because of variable length, so in which encoding wctomb gives the output?

Answer (score 1):

The "wide" and "multibyte" encoding formats of `wctomb` (and other related functions) are platform-dependent, and are likely to also be locale-dependent (see `setlocale` and `LC_CTYPE`). There is no portable way to detect or control which encoding is used.